# R find the nth non-NA element in string

Tags: r

I have data frame with 2 attributes, string and output

```
v.string <- c(
"'NA', 'A', 'NA'",
"'A', 'B', 'NA'",
"'NA'",
"'A'"
)
```

In the field string, there is a series of element which may contain NA or other character. I would like to create a field named output to indicate the nth element which is non NA.

```
v.desiredoutput <- c(2,1,0,1)

df <- data.frame(string=v.string, output=v.desiredoutput)
```

Comment: your `NA`s are not actual `NA` but string "NA" ?

Comment: yes. string 'NA'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the string using `strsplit` and find the first occurrence of non - "'NA'"

```
v <- sapply(strsplit(v.string, ","), function(x) min(which(x != "'NA'")))
v
#[1]   2   1 Inf   1
```

This returns `Inf` for no matches which can be changed to 0 if you want

```
v[is.infinite(v)] <- 0
v
#[1] 2 1 0 1
```

---

A better option by @Shree using `match`

```
sapply(strsplit(v.string, ","), function(x) match(TRUE, x!= "'NA'", nomatch = 0))
#[1] 2 1 0 1
```